# AWS S3 Object Lambda Access Point: The caller is not authorized to invoke the Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I created resources for S3 Object Lambda Access Point following this article:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/

And added all the permissions from this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-policies.html

When I try to make getObject API call, with Object Lambda Access Point ARN instead of bucket name, I get: *An error occurred (LambdaPermissionError) when calling the GetObject operation: The caller is not authorized to invoke the Lambda function.*

I tried to call only lambda invoke API call and it worked. Also, I can get object trough standard access point.
What am I missing here? My aws cli and aws sdk versions are updated.

Comment: Can you give more information? How did you create the access point, how (code) are you calling the API etc.

Comment: I created it manually from Console, exactly like that one in the article. 
I tried calling aws s3api get-object --bucket my-object-lambda-access-point-arn ... and also amazonS3.getObject(lambdaAccessPointArn, key) from java aws sdk (it returned the same error)
What did work was: aws lambda invoke ... and aws s3api get-object --bucket my-standard-access-point-arn ... , from the terminal